# Installing SASS with npm. TypeError

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line, sass

I am new to sass and I want to install it. I already have Node.js and I typed in `npm install -g sass`

I don't know why, but whenever I do `sass --version` it gives me a TypeError. 
[image]

I have NO idea what this error means. I have little experience with the command line. Maybe I typed the command incorrectly? Thanks and sorry for my lack of experience in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had this issue as well on Ubuntu.

Installing an earlier version of sass resolved the issue, e.g `npm install -g sass@1.5.1`.

Comment: Thanks! I installed an older version of sass (1.6.2) and it works!